# placing JPanel at the center using BorderLayout.centre with spaces of 50 pixels at all 4 directions

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I have a JFrame with BorderLayout and I wan to place a single JPanel at the center of JFrame but with spaces of 50 pixels at all directions. That is! when we add a component at the center of BorderLaout then it covers all the space of parent but i want to keep space at all 4 directions. What i did is that i just created panels at north,south ,east and west with 50 pixels width and height.  Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class Abc extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Abc frame = new Abc();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Abc() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 50));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 10));
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 50));
        contentPane.add(panel_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 10));
        contentPane.add(panel_3, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

}
```

What i need is a simple method of creating space at all directions instead of cumbersome job as i did in this code. Is there any method or constructor of BorderLayout to this?

Comment: setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300) did not worked!

Comment: `contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,50,50,50))`

Comment: `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);` Use `pack()` for the size and `setLocationByPlatform(true)` for the location.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code demonstrating use of `EmptyBorder`:

```
package snippet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class Abc extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Abc frame = new Abc();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Abc() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        contentPane.add(panel);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

    }
}
```